# How to insert slides into multiple ppt files automatically

Tags: office365, powerpoint

I have roughly a hundred ppt files. I need to insert a fix set of slides into all these ppt files automatically.

The use case is an education institute has roughly a hundred classes - each class has a ppt file in a centralized repository. Now I want to make a "institute wide announcement" so I want to insert those slides into each of the ppt.

Obviously I don't want to open each file and insert the slides manually. Is there an automated way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you could do this with a VBA macro. Here are the basics for batch operations on a group of files: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00536_Batch-_Do_something_to_every_file_in_a_folder.htm Then for the actual process of inserting the slides, the answers on this page should get you there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891687/copy-one-slide-to-multiple-presentation